# Рендринг React компонентов через PHP

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, reactjs

Всем привет!
На сервере(nodejs) есть React который рендрит компоненты и отдает их клиенту.
 Если это делать на прямую(nodejs-браузер) то проблем нет.

Но мне нужна такая схема:
1. Пользователь запрашивает страницу у приложения на PHP
2. PHP приложение каким-то чудесным образом обращается к реакту на nodejs
3. Реакт рендрит нужную страницу
4. PHP приложение получает отрендринную страницу от реакта и отдает клиенту

Получается PHP приложение выступает как прокси между клиентом и nodejs с реактом

Как такое можно реализовать? С чего начать, куда копать?
Как связать nodejs и php?

Comment: А вы знаете толк в извращениях. Зачем вам именно через php отдавать страницы?

Comment: Это нужно для SEO оптимизации SPA приложения

Comment: Почитайте про curl в php

Comment: Я знаю что такое curl. Такой вариант не подходит, т.к. придется слать запросы через http а сервис  высоконагруженный. Нашел вот такую штуку https://github.com/phpv8/v8js, но могу подозревать что она не подойдет. Нужна помощь от человека который реально решал такую задачу

Comment: @XYZ во первых сам curl немножно туповат - его можно поднастроить, чтобы он работал быстрее - без этого у запросов будут адовы задержки. Во вторых - `придется слать запросы через http а сервис высоконагруженный` - а по вашему http не дружит с высоконагруженностью? Ну и ещё один вариант - `exec` (или подобная ф-я вроде `pcntl_exec`) из PHP - выполняете, получаете результат, хотите синхронно, хотите асинхронно, исключая прослойку вебсервера.

Answer (score 0):

это не конкретное решение, а направление по его поиску. автору явно уже не нужно решение, но для целей SEO оптимизации SPA приложения часто используют серверный рендеринг (SSR). это коротко не описать, придется отправить в поиск по указанным словам. что лучше, чем делать пострендеринг. сам стоял в эти годы перед таким же выбором и все решилось использованием express, хотя сейчас есть уже и другие варианты. тем более что уже используется nodejs, нет смысла добавлять php.

Comment: Мы тоже тогда решили отказаться от php (хотя проект уже был почти написан) и переписать на серверный js с пререндрингом.

Answer (score -1):

Через настройку web-сервера.

Например: апач направляет определённые адреса на PHP (например с определённым портом), а другие на nodejs, на другой порт. Причём порт nodejs закрыт для доступа извне. В итоге из PHP ты посылаешь HTTP запрос на свой же сервер, с помощью curl например - но на другой порт. Выходит прокси в чистом виде.

Но надо предупредить - такой подход весьма замедлит работу запросов.